# how to store pass data from one value to another value using javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am developing one quiz game in which I have set of rules. For every correct question user should get +3 marks, so I have define one variable. One page and have set the value, but I don't know how to carry to next page

```
    function Question1cont() {
         var mark;
         var x = document.getElementById("fermi").checked;
         var y= document.getElementById("Newton").checked;
         var z= document.getElementById("Angstrom").checked;
         var q= document.getElementById("Tesla").checked;
         if ( x === true)
         {
           mark = 3;
         }
         if ( y === true)
         {
           mark = -1;
         }

         if ( z === true) 
         {
           mark = -1;
         }

         if ( q === true) 
         {
           mark = -1;
         }

         if ( y === false && z=== false && q === false && x=== false )
         {
             mark = 0;
             alert ( "please any answer then continue");
             return false;
         }
         window.location = "file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/practice/images/Question_2.html";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to send the results of the form to the subsequent page.  There is where you do the work to determine the value of what just got passed in.

Alternately, you can have a hidden object where you place the value, and send that as part of the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="values" name="values" value="">
```

As it stands right now, you are trying to send the whole thing to "location"

```
window.location = "file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/practice/images/Question_2.html";
```

That will not pass anything along.  You need to send your form with a `action="Question_2.html"` on it

I don't see in your code where your form is in the HTML.  Presumably you have a  tag like this:

```
<form name="thisform" action="Question_2.html" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having all the "pages" in one HTML document? Then you wouldn't have to worry about passing state/variables around between pages:

```
<div id="page1" style="display:none">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fermi" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="Newton" />
</div>
<div id="page2" style="display:none">
    <!-- Other questions here -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    QuestionCheck();
    // Code here to hide one div tag and show the other, etc
</script>
```

Another way is to pass variables via the query string of the URL. https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+read+query+string

If this is being hosted on a server, then you'll be able to use the `localStorage` JavaScript object https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage (I'm not sure it works when running local files).